# Quadtree in javascript

Tags: javascript, data-structures, quadtree

I have been working in jQuery and I was given this code for a quadtree in javascript:

```
map = array(
    array(array(1,2,3,4), array(1,2,3,4), array(1,2,3,4), array(1,2,3,4)),
    array(array(1,2,3,4), array(1,2,3,4), array(1,2,3,4), array(1,2,3,4)),
    array(array(1,2,3,4), array(1,2,3,4), array(1,2,3,4), array(1,2,3,4)),
    array(array(1,2,3,4), array(1,2,3,4), array(1,2,3,4), array(1,2,3,4))
);

map[0][3][3] = "END OF ARRAY 1";
map[1][3][3] = "END OF ARRAY 2";
```

However this just looks like a 3d array to me, am I being stupid? ^.^

Comment: one `$` sign alone does not justify a `jQuery` tag.

Comment: Edited, apologies - I got the code and put it up without editing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So technically this *is* a quadtree, but it's not what most people would expect if you said "here's some quadtree code".

Quadtree code would normally mean a class that handles building such a tree by inserting objects with 2D coordinates, then finding intersecting or nearby objects.

E.g. see http://www.mikechambers.com/blog/2011/03/21/javascript-quadtree-implementation/

Answer (score 6):

Since all nodes have **exactly four children** it *is* a quadtree. It is also a 3D array, since it is three levels deep.

Comment: Thank you - I get confused so easily :/